# How to crop space after applying drop shadow?

Tags: inkscape, crop, shadows, drop-shadow

In Inkscape I have drawn a square and then applied **Drop Shadow** filter to it.

How could I please get rid of the appeared top and left space?

[image: Inkscape]

I need to have the top-left corner of the yellow square at the point **0, 0** - so that I could resize the document size to just the square and the shadow (then I would export it as bitmap(s) and use in my app).

In Gimp I would just apply **Image - Autocrop**, but how to do it in Inkscape?

Comment: I suppose you want an automatisable solution?

Comment: No, I actually wondered about how to do it manually, while editing the SVG file in Inkscape. Drop shadow filter has added padding around the rectangle - so I wonder how to get rid of it at top and left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After applying the drop shadow to the rectangle, go to filter general settings in the  filter editor dialog. Change the values for co-ordinates x & y which displaces the top left origin point of the rectangle. Similarly adjust the dimensions correspondingly to retain the same width & height for the shadow.

[image: Filter editor]

The values specified in the image is the default value. You may need to vary those values to get the required origin point for selection.

Comment: +1 and thank you for this great answer, but I am still curious - what happened to my rectangle after I have applied the *Drop Shadow* filter to it. I have tried *Selecting All in All Layers* (the single layer in my Inkscape document is unlocked) and then *Ungroup* - but nothing happens. I was hoping to ungroup rectangle and shadow and then move them a bit to the top-left - to get rid of the unwanted padding manually.

Comment: Filters are a feature of SVG that allow an SVG viewer to change the presentation of an object in a well-defined manner such as adding texture to a Fill, giving an object a blurred shadow, or modifying the object's color (referred from http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-Preset.html). As per the manual applying filters is nothing but changing the appearance of the object. For example when a object is filled with some color or pattern, you cannot see the applied fill/ pattern details in the layer and the only way of editing is using its own dialog (Fill & stroke).

Comment: Similarly if filters have to be edited you need to use the filter editor dialog. That is how you can control the  filters. Ungrouping the object doesn't separate the object from applied filter (drop shadow).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the export area when exporting, e.g., with the following command-line option:

```
--export-area=20:20:220:220
```